# Write SQL Result back to a Table Column

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, sql-insert

I have the following query:

```
-- Calculate Clock Position & Structural Grade
SELECT IIF(clock_to - clock_at_from < 0,
           12 - (clock_at_from - clock_to),
           clock_to - clock_at_from) AS clock_pos_calc,
       IIF(clock_pos_calc = 1, 3,
       IIF(clock_pos_calc = 2, 4,
       IIF(clock_pos_calc > 3, 5, NULL))) AS clock_pos_value
FROM Conditions;
```

I want to add the results of these queries back to the Conditions table to the following fields which already exist.

```
WRITE clock_pos_calc TO clock_pos
WRITE clock_pos_value TO structural_grade if NULL
```

Yet not sure how. I've tried UPDATE and INSERTS yet can't get it to play nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query for update statement

```
update Conditions 
set clock_pos = IIF(clock_to - clock_at_from < 0,
           12 - (clock_at_from - clock_to),
           clock_to - clock_at_from),
structural_grade = IIF(IIF(clock_to - clock_at_from < 0,
       12 - (clock_at_from - clock_to),
       clock_to - clock_at_from) = 1, 3,
       IIF(IIF(clock_to - clock_at_from < 0,
       12 - (clock_at_from - clock_to),
       clock_to - clock_at_from) = 2, 4,
       IIF(IIF(clock_to - clock_at_from < 0,
       12 - (clock_at_from - clock_to),
       clock_to - clock_at_from) > 3, 5, NULL)))
WHERE clock_pos IS NULL OR structural_grade IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx) construct for this purpose like

```
INSERT INTO Conditions (clock_pos, structural_grade)
SELECT IIF(clock_to - clock_at_from < 0,
           12 - (clock_at_from - clock_to),
           clock_to - clock_at_from) AS clock_pos_calc,
       IIF(clock_pos_calc = 1, 3,
       IIF(clock_pos_calc = 2, 4,
       IIF(clock_pos_calc > 3, 5, NULL))) AS clock_pos_value
FROM Conditions
WHERE clock_pos IS NULL
OR structural_grade IS NULL;
```